# Need to display Columns wise last 12 months of data Quarterly

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want display Last 12 Month Data quarterly on the basis of current month .
    For Example current Month is June then my data should display 4 grouping set JUNE-MAY-APRIL ,JUNE-MAY-APRIL,DEC-NOV-OCT,SEPT-AUG-JULY

Below is the format i want to display
[image]

```
Below is the sql query i am try

    DECLARE @ANYDATE DATETIME
    SET @ANYDATE=GETDATE()

     SELECT TOP 20 DATePART(MONTH,@ANYDATE) [MONTH],
     DATePART(QUARTER,@ANYDATE) [Quarter], COUNT(1) [ACount]
     FROM ACTIVITY ACC
     INNER JOIN Accounts A ON ACC.Relatedtoid = A.ACCOUNTID
        AND ACC.OWNERID = A.OWNERID
     WHERE ACC.layoutid = 1015
        AND ACC.ownerid = 402
        AND A.LAYOUTID IN (
            104442
            ,104451
            ,104436
            )           
       GROUP BY 
      DATePART(MONTH,ACC.CREATEDON),DATePART(QUARTER,ACC.CREATEDON)
      ORDER BY 1,2

OUTPUT OF CURRENT QUERY
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Chetan You need to write **[PIVOT](https://coding-vila.blogspot.com/2019/05/pivot-and-unpivot-in-sql-server-with-example.html)** query, please follow this link to know how to write **[PIVOT](https://coding-vila.blogspot.com/2019/05/pivot-and-unpivot-in-sql-server-with-example.html)** query in SQL server: [PIVOT and UNPIVOT in SQL server](https://coding-vila.blogspot.com/2019/05/pivot-and-unpivot-in-sql-server-with-example.html)

Comment: please provide us an output of current query.

Comment: @kirangadhe  QUERY output is added

Comment: now the required output is missing

Comment: @kirangadhe. I just want output in four grouping set  Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4